# UrlConnection Iphone

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I am trying to get data from a server using the following code.

```
+ (NSString *) getData:(NSString *)methodName parameters:(NSDictionary *) parameters error:(NSError **)error
{
 NSString *body  = [UdoziProxy getRequestBody:methodName parameters:parameters];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [UdoziProxy createRequest:body];

 // Send the request .
 NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;

 NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:error];

 if (responseData == nil || error !=nil) {

  return nil;

 }

 return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

It works fine when the server is running but when I stop the server deliberately, the responseData object has still value and is not nil. How can I handle the situation where either the connection is lost or the server is down ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [cache policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequest) on your `NSURLRequest` object. If the synchronous API still doesn't honour that, you need to switch to using the asynchronous API and throw away the cache request object when you receive it. If *that* doesn't work, then maybe your network has a transparent proxy which is doing some caching for you.

Comment: I set the cache policy to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData but didn't work.

Comment: @Mo Agh: I've added more options for you to try.

Comment: The thing is I need to send the request synchronously

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement NSURLConnection delegates in

you can get failure status in 
the following delegate

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
```

responseData =nil
}

there you have to make the recieved data  to nil value

also its safe to
get data in

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

{  }

which indicates that the connection is finished